# X-Window Modeline for high resolution modes on NEC LCD 22WV monitor

Tags: linux, display, lcd, x-windows, modeline

What should look like X Window System (X.Org) modeline to be put in xorg.conf, for high resolution (incuding recommended 1680x1050 @ 50Hz resolution) for 22" NEC LCD 22WV monitor?  X.Org autodetect correctly only 800x600 and lower resolution SVGA modes, unfortunately.<sup>1,2</sup>

How can I **generate** proper "Modeline" line for xorg.conf?  Is information included in [NEC_Datasheet_LCD22WV-english.pdf](http://www.nec-display-solutions.co.uk/p/download/pr/File/cp/Products/LCD/Current/LCD-LCD22WV/Datasheets/Datasheet-%28english%29_uk.pdf?fn=NEC_Datasheet_LCD22WV-english.pdf&e=e4s1) enough (found on [NEC LCD 22WV product info](http://www.nec-display-solutions.co.uk/p/uk/en/support/product/dp/Products/LCD/Current/LCD-LCD22WV/LCD-LCD22WV.xhtml?e=e4s1) page)?

What tools there are available to generate proper modeline for a LCD monitor for Linux?  MS Windows (MS Windows XP Home) correctly detects and use 1680x1050 resolution; can I somehow get modeline information from MS Windows?

---

**Footnotes:**
<sup>1)</sup> It might be *hardware problem* with the monitor itself, as the same LiveCD Linux distribution that couldn't autodetect recommended 1680x1050 mode for NEC LCD 22WV monitor, correctly autodetects recommended 1440x900 mode for slightly smaller NEC LCD 19WV monitor from the same family, by the same producent.

<sup>2)</sup> Or it might be problem with graphics card (NVIDIA Riva TNT2 M64) not supporting such resolution, or with graphics driver not supporting such resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution may be helpful even if you don't use Ubuntu

Often it's enough to just set HorizSync and VertRefresh in /etc/X11/xorg.conf to your monitor's values.

Answer (score 2):

`cvt` and `gtf` can both be used to generate modelines. They come with Xorg.